# Invalid Operation Exception , No elements in the sequence

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

```
private static void WriteJson(string filepath, 
                              string filename, 
                              JsonSchema jsonschema)
        {
        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(
                       @"C:\Users\ashutosh\Desktop\Output\" + filename + ".js"))
        using (var jtw = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
            {
            jtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jsonschema.WriteTo(jtw);
            }
        //var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        //        jsonschema, Formatting.Indented, 
        //        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
        //                 NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
        //    File.WriteAllText(
        //       @"C:\Users\ashutosh\Desktop\Output\" + filename + ".js", json);
        }
```

I am creating a JSONSchema from JSON.net , and then writing it out . I get a

```
Invalid Operation Exception Sequence contains no matching element
```

But when I use the commented code instead of the usual stuff. No such exception appears.

1) What is causing this exception?
2) I would have used the second method happily but it doesn't feel intuitive and it will print out the integer value of the JsonType for schema.Type instead of the (array,integer,bool etc..)

**What can I do to get out of this situation?**

**UPDATE**
The exception happens when the "`Properties`" property of the `JsonSchema` has count  = 0 .
`Properties` is `Dictionary<String,JsonSchema>`. I have initialise it so it is not null. Eventually the code may or may not add elements to it . so , the count may remain 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, enums will be serialized to theirs corresponding integer value. You can change that easily by supplying [`StringEnumConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) in your serializer settings:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonschema, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new StringEnumConverter() }
    });
```

**Edit**:

I run this simple test code:

```
var schema = new JsonSchemaGenerator().Generate(typeof(CustomType));
Debug.Assert(schema.Properties.Count == 0);
using (TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText(@"schema.json"))
using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
{
    jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    schema.WriteTo(jsonTextWriter);
}

// CustomType is a class without any fields/properties
public class CustomType { }
```

Code above serializes schema correctly to:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {}
}
```

Is the schema you are generating correct? It seems as if serializer was "thinking" it should deal with some properties when there are actually none. Can you show type you generate schema from? There might be a problem with type which causes invalid schema to generate - but still, I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: firstly your answer correctly solves my second problems. Thank you. I will update my question to provide you with a snapshot of the jsonschema. I am tempted to mark this as answer , which i will soon. But i want more attention to the earlier part also , because that has really puzzled me.

Comment: is there a way of telling the serialiser to not print a particular property . e.g. i have AllowAddtionalProperties = true , printed like a zillion times in my schema. How can i turn this off ??

Comment: @immy_keen sincere apologies for de-accepting the answer. I will accept it later once we get a handle on the exception message as well.

Comment: @ashutoshraina: schema with `Properties` count of `0` serializes correctly for me. Can you provide more details on schema you use/type you generate schema from?